# "Sina Weibo" and "Weibo"

Tags: discussion, retag-request

According to their current tag descriptions, [weibo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weibo) (41 questions) and [sinaweibo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sinaweibo) (21 questions) seem to be about the same thing: the service/website [Sina Weibo](http://weibo.com/).

[*All* 21 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sinaweibo+weibo) questions that used [sinaweibo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sinaweibo) also used [weibo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weibo).

I don’t know this service, but according to Wikipedia, [*Weibo* is the Chinese word for "microblog"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microblogging_in_China), while [*Sina Weibo* is a specific service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sina_Weibo).

So I think we should keep [sinaweibo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sinaweibo) (and ideally rename it to [sina-weibo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sina-weibo)) and get rid of [weibo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weibo) (by retagging all questions that used [weibo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weibo) with [sina-weibo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sina-weibo)).

Comment: What is the relationship of these tags to programming, that makes the questions appropriate for this site at all?

Comment: @BenVoigt: The same as [tag:facebook] or [tag:twitter]. A tag alone does not need to be related to programming, it only needs to describe the content of the question. The question itself needs to be appropriate.

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah... and it looks like the similar influx of off topic questions, like http://stackoverflow.com/q/13627549/103167 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/25867227/103167 which are asking about terms of use.

Comment: I say nuke both tags from orbit, and have only `sina-weibo-api`.  If the question is about that site and not about the API, it is off-topic.

Comment: There is also Tencent microblog （Tengxun Weibo). So SinaWeibo is only a subset of Weibo.

Comment: So, then, *weibo* is (1) a generic term, and (2) not English.  It probably should not exist, regardless of the fate of [sinaweibo].

Comment: Adding a hyphen is worse, not better.

Comment: @TylerH The hyphen tells us at a glance that it's not the two words "sinaw eibo", or some other combination.  It's better with the hyphen

Comment: @Izkata Glancing at tags is for people who know what they are. If you don't know what a given tag is, the tooltip on hover provides information including the name spaced out properly.

Comment: @TylerH Good point. Let's change [tag:ruby-on-rails] to [tag:rubyonrails] and [tag:google-maps-api-3] to [tag:googlemapsapi3]. So what if it makes your eyes bleed...just read the tooltip.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Shouldn't your username be This-Suit-Is-Black-Not?

Comment: There's a "microblogging" tag which is seemingly more generic than 'weibo' (since it applies globally, not just to Chinese microblogs). And the term is recognizable enough to plenty of English speakers (see, say, http://www.economist.com/topics/sina-weibo), including the people answering the questions. Having 'weibo' seems useful because some people will type it instead of 'sinaweibo', as they do in some question titles. Poster's intent was clearly good, but I'm wary of changing tags on unfamiliar topics based on Google searches.

Comment: @TylerH My username isn't used for categorizing tens of thousands of questions like the tags I cited. Nor is there a long-established convention for dash-separating usernames like there is for tags. Readability matters, even for tags.

Comment: @TylerH No need to separate words in two ways at once.  If tags were PascalCase like his name, I wouldn't care about the hyphens.  But tags are all lowercase with no spaces, so word separation is done a different way

Comment: On the proposal to keep only sina-weibo-api, a "no tags about sites" rule would mean we should also nuke 'facebook' and 'twitter'. I think the unfamiliarity ("*I'd* never use these tags") is causing us to treat them more strictly than we do similar existing ones.

Comment: @twotwotwo: I've never used the [tag:facebook] or [tag:twitter] tags and I'd support renaming those to facebook-api or facebook-webservice or whatever kind of API they actually have.  Possibly multiple tags, if there's more than one flavor of API for access to the same web application.

Comment: @twotwotwo For example, if [tag:facebook] is supposed to mean the Facebook API, then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388714/mention-someone-in-a-facebook-comment-on-my-website) shouldn't be using it.  Perhaps it should carry a tag for some wordpress-facebook gateway API, or perhaps it is completely off-topic.  I don't know anything about the programming model of the wordpress-facebook gateway plugin(s) to tell the difference.

Comment: @BenVoigt Big picture, I can imagine having a policy that that tags that can apply to non-programming questions are suspect, but I don't think one exists now, and adding it could affect a lot of tags (facebook, twitter, soundcloud, android, iphone, ios8, excel-2010, and maybe broader ones like email, multilingual, asynchronous, etc.). Allowing tags that might also apply to non-programming topics, and moderating posted questions, seems to basically work. Given that I support asker's proposal to keep the tags.

Comment: @twotwotwo It is possible that `weibo` should be made a subtag, or an alias, or whatever, of `microblogging`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot My response was tongue-in-cheek because your comment was not quite relevant. I was referring specifically to this tag, not all tags.

Comment: @DavidConrad Could work.

Comment: @TylerH There is a convention for tag naming. That's what my comment was meant to illustrate. Perhaps we should just say what we mean instead of using all these half-assed analogies ;)

Comment: regarding the idea that "facebook" "ios" "pinterest" etc should not have tags (or should legalistically have "API!" added).  It's Just Silly.  It's one of those things that makes people think SO is really silly.

Comment: If "weibo" is the generic term for "something like Sina-Weibo", then could we have an English word instead, such as "microblog"?  It seems odd to have a Chinese word used as a tag on an English site.

Comment: @DavidWallace Not odd in a general sense.  "Wiki" is not an English word, yet we use it.  The standard should be something like "what is the most understood term for X among the SO community".

Comment: @JasonMArcher  I feel that "wiki" IS in fact an English word.  Most words in English have come in from another language - some more recently than others.  What makes something an English word is whether the majority of English speakers know what it means.  I feel that most of us know what "wiki" means, but most of us don't know what "weibo" means.

Comment: Also, "wiki" meaning "a particular type of web site" is definitely English - in its original language, "wiki" means "quick".

Comment: Indeed, note that "face book" had a meaning (ask at a modelling agency) before "Facebook" and "googol" had a meaning before Google.  However, it would be insane to suggest "oh, we must spell out that Facebook means the USA 'social media' company!" as opposed to the other meaning.  (Indeed, you might as well say, it would be insane to demand "c" is noted everywhere as "c - the programming language!" rather than the letter "c" that etymologists study.)

Answer (score 15):

In China, there are four companies that offer a microblogging (weibo in Chinese) service, sina, tencent, netease and sohu, but most Chinese people like to use sina's service, so most of the time, weibo means sina microblog, also, sina get the domain weibo.com.

Comment: As a Chinese, I didn't even know `netease` is `网易`...

Answer (score -16):

Ni hao, "Weibo" is the planet's main "social" dotcom.  It has some **five hundred million** users.

(You may have heard of the similar much smaller companies in the "West" (they have names like 'facebook', 'twitter' etc.). One would assume weibo will just buy these out imminently so if you're reading this in the future and have no clue what I'm talking about, 'facebook' etc were funny little "western" versions of Weibo.)

Apparently the most popular weibo users now (2014) have some **fifty million** "followers".

(It's - really incredible - that people who work on the internet for a living don't know this!  It would be like working in the car industry and not knowing what "Ford" is.)

I believe "Sina Weibo" is simply the full name of "Weibo".  There would be no reason at all to have both tags, I guess.

(As there's no need for "Apple" and also "Vertical Hardware and Software Maker" or "Twitter" and "Short form live messaging services", or so to speak "hoover" and "vacuum".)

Comment: What is the reason behind all this "marketing", instead of going directly to the point? If I'm not mistaken, you spent three paragraphs on telling us, how cool "Weibo" is and only one paragraph on actually answering the question.

Comment: From the question *"I don’t know this service..."*  Trejder, welcome to SO.  SO is often **insane**.  To counter insanity, sometimes you have to be exceptionally clear and repetitive. As in my analogy: in the auto industry, confusion involving not knowing what Ford is, or in the film industry confusion regarding not knowing what Disney is, would require some initial extensive clarification.  to sort of reduce the bizarre level.  Have a nice day, talk to you next year.

Comment: re. hyperbole, Facebook had 1.3 billion active users (as of June 2014). Anyhow, the relative size of these social networks is besides the point: the name of service you refer to is indeed Sina Weibo, and there are other Weibo services. Using “Weibo” to refer to Sina Weibo is analogous to referring to “Wikipedia” as “Wiki” – you will probably be understood, but other wikis exist…

Comment: Ni hao. I encourage you to look up the URL.

Comment: @trejder I think Joe Blow's point in the first four paragraphs is a response to [comments suggesting that the tags are inappropriate for the site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274467/sina-weibo-and-weibo#comment105904_274467) or [that they should have "-api" appended to them](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274467/sina-weibo-and-weibo#comment105937_274467), which would be a departure from what is done for other major sites like Facebook and Twitter.

Comment: @JoeBlow I'm aware of their `weibo.com` URL, but being the biggest weibo (or indeed big enough to be generically referred to as “weibo”) does not remove the existence of other weibos. (In my western bubble I first became aware of Sina Weibo's existence when working on an app that had support for sharing to two different weibos…)

Comment: I think the flashy writing is because, based on our personal experience out here, it *feels* like Sina Weibo is not a topic as important as Facebook or Twitter. It can be hard to change minds about that when people have literally never heard of Sina Weibo but use Facebook or Twitter a lot. So Joe's pouring on the emphasis (+#s) to try to overcome that resistance.

Comment: I disagree with having 'weibo' as a synonym for 'sina-weibo' because there are other weibos. Like, a question about Tencent Weibo, or "Is there an open-source weibo project I could deploy inside my corporate intranet?" are legit weibo-but-not-sina-weibo questions.

Comment: hi @twotwotwo, quite right. regarding having "weibo" to mean "social site" ... I guess since this site (SO) is mainly in English, the tag would just be "microblogging" (rather than "weibo").  And sure, "sina-weibo" is the best tag for that company.

Comment: Weibo has 500m users and they are all Chinese since all other social networks are blocked out there...

Comment: Indeed, 500m (real) users, $6b valuation, one of the most talked-about enterprises. It's sort of .. let's just say insular, a bit silly .. that folks who work everyday with Fabulous American companies like Samsung, Sony, Nintendo, Lenovo, Foxconn's new 6 and 6plus, etc, are at sea with Weibo.  Anyways.  Perhaps xiaomi should buy them out.

Comment: Samsung is not American, nor is Nintendo or Sony

Comment: Also Lenovo is actually chinese

Comment: And just go go that extra mile, Foxconn is also not American